# Click Toggle (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, toggle

```
$("li").hover(
function () {
    // do x
},
function () {
    // do y
});
```

.. thats for hover, how would I do the same for click toggle, i.e do x on click and y on second click?

Manythanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$('li').toggle(function() {
 alert(1)
}, function() {
 alert(2);
});
```

Comment: .toggle() is REMOVED in 1.9, use 1.8 or earlier.

Answer (score 11):

[`$.toggle()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/toggle#fnfn2fn3.2Cfn4.2C...) will take any number of functions. Here it is with two:

```
$("li").toggle(
  function() { /* do x */ },
  function() { /* do y */ }
);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vbkBQ/

Comment: It took me a long time to try and find this. You can also do this with click and hover - brilliant. I wanted to know how to do the if else inside a function like this.. repped. Bookmarked.

Answer (score 0):

One problem with toggle() is that it automatically calls `event.preventDefault()`. Here's one way that will let you leave the default action in place or allow you to only call it conditionally.

```
$("a").click(function(event){
    var toggle = ($(this).data('toggle') == undefined) ? true : $(this).data('toggle');
    console.log(toggle);

    if(toggle){
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    $(this).data('toggle', !toggle);
});​​
```